# Adding some content to a <text> tag through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

Bit stuck on getting this to work.

Had issues with the backend changing a string from x to x*. Please take the Asterix literally.

I am trying to get around this by using 'contains()' JQuery to detect the text, and apply a class to it.

```
<text fill="#FF8201" style="font-size: 13.2px;" x="0" y="327.58888888888885" fill-opacity="1">JIMMY</text>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("text:contains(JIMMY)").addClass('an');
 });
```

CSS:

```
text.an::after {
content: '*';
}
```

But it's not working. Not sure why...

Comment: What kind of tag is `<text>`? Never seen it before. It's not HTML.

Comment: It's a D3 SVG Text Field

Comment: It's working in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7vag4eo6/

Comment: SVG does not support pseudo elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a vanilla Javascript solution in which we create a function called `changeText` which takes two arguments `queryText`: the text to search for and `appendText` the text to be appended at the end of the queryText.

```js
//function searches for all <text> elements within svg tags for the queryText 
//  and then appends them with the appendText
function changeText(queryText, appendText) {
    let textElements = document.querySelectorAll('svg text'); // get all text elements within SVG as a NodeList
    textElements.forEach(el => {  // go through each text element
        if (el.innerHTML === queryText) { // if the innerHTML matches the query HTML then
            el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + appendText; // append the text
        }
    })
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //pass in the search text and the appending text as arguments
    changeText('JIMMY', '*');
});
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="500">
  <text fill="#FF8201" style="font-size: 13.2px;" x="0" y="10" fill-opacity="1">JIMMY</text>
  <text fill="#FF8201" style="font-size: 13.2px;" x="0" y="30" fill-opacity="1">NOT JIMMY</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Coola, thanks for your response. 

Do I have to set the variables of query text or anything?

Comment: To answer your question, you just pass in the variables into the function like `changeText('JIMMY', '*')`. It is very strange, that it is not working and it may not be working due to some sort of loading issue (i.e. the order in which the script is loading vs the data being populated) or maybe the text is not an exact match? I can only help debug more if you could share the page or something where you are seeing it, cause otherwise I cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: Is your D3.js visualization fetching the  data from somewhere and then producing the graph. If so, this function may have to be run after the graph is drawn, for example.

Comment: Hi Coola, yes that is correct, the visualisation pulls in data.

It's been a lot of work for a single astrix. I have decided not to include it and focus elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the comments above, there is a JSFiddle that is linked. When viewing that, I see no problem, as the `*` is visible. The only thing I noticed was that you were using JQuery, so my only thought on this is if you haven't liked your JQuery or CSS properly. As you may know, you can link to JQuery by using a CDN:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can download the JQuery files and attach it from a local file:

```
<script src="/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or it could be a problem in linking the CSS file (which contains the class styles):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Other than that, I have no idea.